# Laptop no longer wakes up from sleep when opened

Tags: power-management, laptop, 19.10

I am running Ubuntu 19.10. Since yesterday, when I close and then open my laptop, the screen remains dark and it doesn't wake up when I use the keyboard. I have to restart it with REISUB or the power button. How can I diagnose and fix this?

I have been installing a lot of software lately, so I'm not sure what's responsible. This started happening around the same time as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218982/laptop-no-longer-wakes-up-from-sleep-when-opened).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, report can be followed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/1868433)