# Ubuntu no longer sees my speakers

Tags: sound, 19.10

When I go to the sound settings, the only output device listed by Ubuntu is "Dummy output". I can't hear any sound. My bluetooth headphones still work if I connect those. These symptoms appeared recently, around the same time as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218982/laptop-no-longer-wakes-up-from-sleep-when-opened).

I ran `aplay -l` and it says `no soundcards found`.

Also worth noting that I dualboot Windows (although I never use Windows) and Windows can play sound through my speakers just fine.

Ubuntu 19.10 on a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Check your kernal version by running `uname -r`

If the version is 5.3.x or higher, follow the below steps:

1. Reboot your system. AT GRUB, choose Ubuntu and press E. You will be taken to command line options.
2. Locate the line beginning with Linux. Add the following parameter at the end of the line snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0
3. Press F10 to reboot.

After verifying this has indeed solved your sound issue, you can make this change permanently by performing the below steps

1. Run sudo gedit /etc/default/grub from terminal.
2. Locate the line beginning with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append the above parameter to it. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
3. Save and Close gedit.
4. Run sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
5. Reboot.

Please check the below question:
[No Sound (Dummy Output) error Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218398/no-sound-dummy-output-error-ubuntu-19-10/1218764#1218764)

Comment: That worked, thank you. Sorry about that, it seems this is a duplicate.